# Android static object lifecycle

Tags: android, static, android-lifecycle, static-members

I am creating event search application, we set search criteria from one screen populate in another screen then user can edit search criteria from 3rd screen and goes to 4th screen.

To achieve above task i am using static object which remember the values around the application and i don't need to do any thing extra.

But i am afraid if about static object life cycle in android if low memory found android delete static objects ???

As android supports multi tasking, if user switches to another application and when user comes back application start acting crazy, does static object get removed when it multi task ??? any idea ?? and also suggest holding static object via singleton method is better approach ???

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Lets start with a bit of background: What happens when you start an application?
The OS starts a process and assigns it a unique process id and allocates a process table.A process start an instance of DVM(Dalvik VM); Each application runs inside a DVM.
A DVM manages class loading unloading, instance lifecycle, GC etc.

Lifetime of a static variable: A static variable comes into existence when a class is loaded by the JVM and dies when the class is unloaded.

So if you create an android application and initialize a static variable, it will remain in the JVM until one of the following happens:

1. the class is unloaded
2. the JVM shuts down
3. the process dies

Note that the value of the static variable will persist when you switch to a different activity of another application and none of the above three happens. Should any of the above three happen the static will lose its value.

You can test this with a few lines of code:

1. print the uninitialized static in onCreate of your activity -> should print null
2. initialize the static. print it -> value would be non null
3. Hit the back button and go to home screen. Note: Home screen is another activity.
4. Launch your activity again -> the static variable will be non-null
5. Kill your application process from DDMS(stop button in the devices window).
6. Restart your activity -> the static will have null value.

Comment: I want to know why I lose my field value in application object if it is not static when I start new activity for example I declare variable current page in application object and its value always return to zero when I open new activity

Comment: when I call super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState); I lose my variable even if they are static , what is the problem ?

Comment: You need to save them first through `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method.

Comment: what if I initialize the static instance in `Application.onCreate` ?

Comment: this is a nice explanation (so no -1) but it's a bit inconsequential: the OP asked explicitly about "low memory situations" (same reason why I'm here), where as far as I know the Os might kill the VM and restart it later with the same parameters, and this case (*IF* it's a real thing) is not covered here...

Comment: after a thorough check, it turns out that Android has different quirks than a standard JVM application and saving anything in the Application as singleton isn't safe. I have added an answer to complement this one.

Comment: I was trying this for a sample application and I found that when I switch to a new Activity, the  static variables value is lost. So my case doesn't seem to be agreeing with your answer. I printed the value before calling `startactivity(intent)` and in the `onCreate` of the new activity. They have different values. Any ideas on how I can check what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @suitianshi I think we can initialize static instances in Application.onCreate, because even if our app goes into background and the process gets killed, as soon as we go back to our app, the Application class will get instantiated and call it's corresponding lifecycle methods again! although I need confirmation on this, I wonder if there could be any scenario where the static instance initialized in Application.onCreate loses its value?

Comment: Static variables do lose their values in low memory situation. The "example of test" is not relevant - it is not low memory

Comment: What I am missing here is an explanation for "1. the class is unloaded"- when would this happen? Would JVM unload a class if it's running low on memory?

Answer (score 17):

Well, the Singleton pattern is also based on using static variables so actually you would be in the same position. While the static approach may work most of the times, it may happen that in some cases when memory is full and another activity takes the foreground before your application moves to its next screen, your activity's process could be killed and you lose the static values.
However Android offers a few options of persisting values between states or transmitting them such as:

- using an Intent, you could pass along
  your search criteria from activity to
  activity (similar to a web http
  request)
- using application preferences, you
  could save the values and retrieve
  them in the activity that needs them
- using the sqlite database you can
  persist them in a table and retrieve
  them later
- if you need to just save activity
  state so that on restart, the fields
  get filled with their previously
  selected values, you can implement
  the onSaveInstanceState() activity
  method - note that this is not
  recommended for between activities
  persistance of states.

You can get some code examples of the usage of preferences, intents and the sqlite database by looking at the [aegis-shield source code tree](http://code.google.com/p/aegis-shield/source/browse/trunk/Aegis+Shield/src/#src/com/googlecode/aegisshield) in google code or in other open source Android applications.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, it turns out that using Application to store singletons is not that great of an idea, unless you are ready to recreate it:

[Don't store data in the application object](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/)

so while [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944564/2177061) is technically correct, it doesn't provide all information.

As the link above suggests, if you really want to stick with that model, you need to be ready to check for null and recreate the data, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

@r1k0 is right here. Storing data in static fields of a class will not persist on its own across application process kills and restarts.  Android routinely kills processes (running apps) when it needs memory.

Per the Android doc: [Activity state and ejection from memory](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem),

> The system never kills an activity directly. Instead, it kills the
>   process in which the activity runs, destroying not only the activity
>   but everything else running in the process, as well.

You can save and restore the state of primitives as well Serializable and Parcelable objects using the methods below.  These are automatically called during the normal activity lifecycle.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {}
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){}
```

So, if you have a class that has only static variables, you can save the state of each field in onSaveInstanceState() and restore them in onRestoreInstanceState(). When Android kills the process that your app is running in, the state of your variables will be saved, and when Android restores your app, the values will be restored in memory in the same state as before.