# Android - storing references to ApplicationContext

Tags: java, android, static, reference

I have a static Preferences class that hold some application preferences and stuff like that. Is it ok to store reference to ApplicationContext there? I need that reference so i can get cache folder and stuff like that in classes that don't inherit Activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to use the `ApplicationContext` there since if you don't [it can cause significant memory leaks](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

However, the problem you have is that the `static` variable may not retain its value.  Due to the way that Android handles applications it is possible that your application could be killed and then restarted - usually due to the user switching to other applications - in such a way that your `static` variable will become null and your code which sets it won't be run.  [Have a look at this question for a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle-application-act-crazy).

It may be possible to work around this problem but testing all the possibilities that may cause your variable to end up `null` would be time-consuming and error prone.  So in my static preference classes I have made any of the methods which require a `Context` take it as an argument.  For example:

```
static int getSomeIntegerPreference(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt(PREFERENCE_SOME_INTEGER, 0);   
}
```

It's ugly but it works.

Comment: Well, I set my Preferences.applicationContext to getApplicationContent() on first activity start. So i think that it should be there unless application dies (VM dies, process gets killer, etc..). And if it dies, on next start it will initialize Preferences.applicationContext again so I think that it should work ok. 

I need something like that, beacuse I need access to context in some classes that don't see getApplicationContext(). For example my Category class need to download icons for each category so i set icon_path to this.

filepath = Preferences.applicationContext.getCacheDir().toString

Comment: You will need to initialize `Preferences.applicationContext` in *every* Activity that uses your `Preferences` class.  Your process could get killed when you're running a different Activity to your first Activity and Android can return user to that point in your application, skipping the first Activity.