# Re-load the app after sleep

Tags: android, libgdx

I found this thread on the libgdx forum and i have the same problem…

I used libGDx and I made a game in August 2012. In this game when I press the stand-by button of my phone(and the screen turns off) and then I press it again, the screen is the same that it was before press the stand by button. 
In the code I didn't write nothing about it, now I want to make another game(using the assetsManager in the splash screen to upload the resources) and when I press the stand by button of my phone and then I press it again the game restarts! so i see the splash-screen again

I used something like this:

```
@Override
public void resume()
{
    super.resume();
    this.setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
}
```

But does not work..

Any solutions? Thanks a lot!!

PS: this is the entire Game class..

```
public static Screen gameScreen;
public static Screen mainMenuScreen;
public static Screen chooseTimeScreen;
public static Screen creditsScreen;
public static AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();;
public static SpriteBatch batcher;
boolean create = false;


@Override
public void create()
{

    Gdx.app.log("----------------", manager + "");

    if (manager == null)
    {
        manager = new AssetManager();
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        setScreen(new SplashScreen(this, manager));
    }
    else
    {
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
    }

}


@Override
public void dispose()
{
    super.dispose();
    manager.dispose();
    batcher.dispose();

    if(gameScreen != null) gameScreen.dispose();
    if(mainMenuScreen != null) mainMenuScreen.dispose();
    if(chooseTimeScreen != null) chooseTimeScreen.dispose();
    if(creditsScreen != null) creditsScreen.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Solution is

1. project.properties file  modify

   target=android-14
2. AndroidManifest.xml file  modify

   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

   add screenSize in the android:configChanges

Comment: I have been looking for the solution for days, adding the "screenSize" to configChanges magically worked for me, **you are the best !!!**

Answer (score 0):

check also what you are doing in the `onCreate` method. This is sometimes called when the screen is awoken from sleep. If you are re-creating your splash screen, or resetting it here, it will be an issue.

Also, your code states `resume()`, should it not be `onResume()`

To avoid recreating your assetmanager in `onCreate` Do something like:

```
if(manager == null)
    manager = new AssetManager();
```

Comment: in the oncreate is do: manager = new AssetManager();
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        setScreen(new SplashScreen(this, manager));

Comment: @ffmm so you are creating a new assetmanager.. replacing the old one. Which essentially resets progress. You need to pause and resume it, but avoid recreating it if it already exists. see example code, to skip recreating if it exists.

Comment: I edit the open post..there is all my code there..
i used you suggestion but now i get a black screen (with some casual texture) when i wakeup the phone

Comment: @ffmm make sure you arent disposing it when you still need it. Or if you do dispose it, set it to null as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `static` variables to track state that needs to get re-loaded on application resume.  Because of the way the Android lifecycle works, a "static" variable reference will (often, but not always) stay valid across a resume, but the actual Android "Activity" will be destroyed.  You should re-create all the resources on resume.  (In your case I think you're not creating them, but you should, and then you use them and they refer to stale state from the old, now dead Activity.)

See [Android static object lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle-application-act-crazy) for a description.

The short answer is that, with libGDX, unless you're absolutely sure about what you are doing, do **not** use `static` variables to track application state, always (re-)create your state in the `create` method.

Comment: hi! thanks for reply!

mm.. i already re-create the manager, the screen and the batcher like you can see in the open post… this still doesn't work..

and i would like re-use the "old" assetManager if i can.. how can i re-use the old assetManager without the static way?

If think the problem is only the assetmanager because when i wake up the phone i see only a white screen but i can hear the button's sound.. so the screen works fine.. the problem is only the textures i think

Comment: I'm pretty sure the AssetManager will have references to OpenGL state that is **lost** (that's why the textures go white), so that's one of the few objects that you absolutely must reload.  Is there a problem with re-creating it?

Comment: :( i wouldn't reload it because i have 5mMb of assets and is so slowly in old devices…at this point there is no difference between reload the entire game or only the assetManager

in this game, for example, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.mazzarol.casualgame.jumperled&hl=it

you can press the stand-by button and when you wake-up the phone you find the correct state…the app doesn't restart… and in that game there aren't precautions for this (the onresume() is not override, and in the oncreate() there is ONLY setScreen(new SplashScreen(game))..but works fine)...