# Variable losing the value

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a class where it contains a variable

```
 public class MyClass
{
    public static string testenome;
    public string Testenome
    {
        get { return testenome; }
        set { testenome = value; }
    }
}
```

When I leave the application in the background I lose the value of the variable as soon as I return.

To some way for me to make that variable stay fixed, only if I close the app so I lose it ?

Comment: shouldn't `testnome` have a private access modifier? also can you provide code of how you're instantiating the class and assigning the value, it's likely this is scope related

Comment: if there is an exception  occurred in your code static value may gone in this case.

Comment: You need to provide more details. This behavoiur seems normal, considering how Android apps work. I recommend reading about the lifecycle of an activity: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050592/436938

Comment: Does MyClass extends Application ?  Also you might need to store and recover the variable value in the activity life cycle onCreate(), onResume() and onPause().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do save that variable in `SharedPreferences` so as it stays in app memory even if its closed.

First set value in `SharedPreferences`

```
//MY_PREFS_NAME - a static String variable like: 
//public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "TestName");
 editor.commit();
```

Now whenever you get back to app after closing it, just get the value of name from `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
```

This is the best way to retain any such vairable until app is uninstalled.