# Static data saved inside singleton is null sometimes when returning to app from background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, static, singleton

I use a classic singleton pattern to store data I get from webServices inside my initial activity (splash activity) and then access it throughout the application.

I have a splash activity which leads to MainActivity which is the sliding menu activity with fragment inside it , the initial fragment is a fragment that contains support map fragment.

my issue is with the data stored inside the singleton , sometimes when the app goes to the background (pressing home and moving to another app) and then go recent apps and choose my application , the singleton's data is null which crashes my app.

I have spent hours checking if my singleton is written as should and what are the possible reasons for static data to become null if I didn't make it null myself .

Following my search I found a great and simple explanation, explaining when/why a static data can become null - [Android static object lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle-application-act-crazy) @Samuh answer and I quote

"So if you create an android application and initialize a static variable, it will remain in the JVM until one of the following happens:
1. the class is unloaded
2. the JVM shuts down
3. the process dies "

About #1 and #2 - I don't really know when these occur.

Regarding #3 - this is perfectly fine as if user will click my app from "recent applications" this will invoke the launcher activity in my case "splash activity" and this will get the data (up to date) from servers and store it again inside my singleton - perfect! , that's exactly what happens inside my other applications , the difference is I'm not using a sliding menu and fragments , only activities. Here in my case returning from background will not invoke the launcher Activity which is the "splash screen" but will invoke the MainActivity (the main sliding menu activity) along with the initial fragment , and when I try to access data from my singleton all data inside it is null, the singleton itself is not null because at the onCreate() of the fragment i use getInstance().I believe that this implies that the singleton was lost and now recreated with no data inside it , so if the process is killed why am I not returned to the launcher activity ?

Hope someone can help , thanks in advance.

My singleton class:

```
 public class MySingleton {
  // some private data members with getters/setters
  private String x,y,z;

      // the instance
  private static MySingleton theInstance = null;

      //private ctor 
      private MySingleton(){
          //doing something 
      }

      //get instance
      public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {

     if (theInstance == null)
        theInstance = new MySingleton ();
     return theInstance;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes your call to `getInstance()` returns null?

Comment: @Ricardo No , getInstance() will never return null , as part of the singleton pattern if the instance inside is null it will create a new instance and return it to you. what I meant is the data stored inside my singleton is null , therefor I know for sure that the singleton is recreated , why it is lost in the first place that's where problem is.

Comment: Just checking. :) I was wondering that maybe you had something wrong in your singleton implementation. Anyway, I think you answered your own question then. It is the OS which is destroying your singleton for whatever reason. Like @Aerilys pointed out, you need to make sure to save the data for recreation to treat those cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your singleton is killed by the system, generally because it needs memory, or because the process is maybe too old.

What I suggest you is:

-Save data from your singleton, in shared prefs for example, so it can be easily recreated if needed. It generally works fine
-Save your variables by overriding OnSaveInstanceState in your Activity, and restore them when   it is recreated.

Comment: thanks for answer ,as I wrote in case of the process gets killed it's perfectly fine , it should invoke the launcher activity which is the splash , the splash will get the up to date data from server and store it again inside my singleton. I don't require saving the data on long term , my purpose is : As long as the app process is alive the singleton data is relevant , if the process dies than no problem the splash should come up and update the data.

Comment: Which parts in the activity are important to you ?

Comment: onCreate/onResume would be interesting I guess. I think that what you need to do is just, when you come back to the MainActivity, if your singleton's data are null, you finish the Activity to come back to the splashscreen.

Comment: I thought of this as a first solution but I'm trying to avoid it cause it seems to me like a "Hack" , what I really don't understand is if the MainActivity is resumed , no chance that the static instance is gone. in fact if the static instance is gone , than clicking the application from "recent apps" shouldn't invoke the Launcher Activity ? is it related to "launchMode" in the manifest ?