# Is an event bus unregister necessary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, event-bus

I'm implementing **MVP** pattern in Android and I'm using **EventBus** to let know the **P**resenter from activity "A" that something happen at activity "B" to update views from "A".

I registered the presenter to EventBus inside in constructor but I don't see any place where I could unregister it.

```
public class PresenterA extends nucleus.presenter.Presenter<ViewA> {

    public PresenterA() {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    public void onEvent(ChangesEvent e) {
        // change views
    }
}
```

1. Is it necessary to unregister at all, when the presenter is suppose to live as long as application (it is not recreated on configuration change)?
2. When user leaves the application (closes activity "A") will the references be freed or is it a memory leak?

Comment: the `Application` doesn't really end until Android kills it as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/27193094/2413303 but having a reference that cannot die would mostly be a problem with View hierarchies (Activities/Fragments).

Comment: EventBus.getDefault() is indeed a static reference, but it holds the reference to presenter which on Activity close is separated from views. Is this considered as memory leak?

Comment: also, if you don´t unregister, some UI code you´ve got in one of the bus event handlers may try to call to an already recycled or disposed view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unregister is important and when user leaves application that does not mean the resources are cleaned instantly
2. Since the EventBus holds static reference to presenter it is not freed until OS kills the process and so, considered as leak.

As for `nucleus.presenter.Presenter` it will be common to register on `onTakeView(ViewType view)` and unregister on `onDropView()` since event handling changes the view