# Common Event Bus Instance

Tags: android, event-bus

I have registered event bus in one activity like - EventBus.getDefault.register(this);

But Now i want to unregister it in to another activity.So how to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an event bus unregister necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486497/is-an-event-bus-unregister-necessary)

Comment: You can do a unregister with  the same registered activity in a different activity if you have the reference to the registered activity. But it is recommended to unregister the activity on the onPause state . otherwise it will give memory leaks .

Comment: @Krish can you please give me a short example?

Comment: post some code where you want to unregister.

Answer (score 1):

> But Now i want to unregister it in to another activity.

You cannot unregister another activity because it is not registerd. You must unregister the same object you registered. Usually `onResume()`/`onPause()` are good place to deal with it.

Comment: but when i remove my application from background then what should i do to unregister the eventbus of that respective activity as i am register it in to onStart() and unregister it in onDestroy() method?

Comment: this sounds like bad design. what you need your activity registered when it is in background?! User may never return to it, so there's no point.

Comment: No,i had created one Subscriber method in launcher activity which i need to be called in others activity by Event posting,that's why i unregister event bus in onDestroy() instead of OnPause().But when application gets removed from background then how should i unregister that event bus?

Comment: @sanil You dont have to unregister the activity if the user kills the apps. It is not a good idea to unregister it in onDestroy.