# Singleton Destruction, Class Loading etc in android

Tags: android, singleton, classloader

I want to get clarity on loading of classes, destruction of objects etc in android because I noticed some weird things happening when using Singleton in My Activity. Best I will describe it using code : 

My Singleton class

```
public class FilterCriteria  {

    private final String TAG=FilterCriteria.class.getSimpleName();
    private static FilterCriteria filterCriteria=new FilterCriteria();

    private FilterCriteria()
    {

    }

    public static FilterCriteria getInstance()
    {
        return filterCriteria;
    }

    private int rentUpperBound,rentLowerBound;
    private int bedrooms,baths;
    private float distance;
    private ObjectStateListener listener;

    public void setFilters(float distance,int baths,int bedrooms,int rentLowerBound,int rentUpperBound) {

        this.distance = distance;
        this.baths=baths;
        this.bedrooms=bedrooms;
        this.rentLowerBound=rentLowerBound;
        this.rentUpperBound=rentUpperBound;
        if(listener!=null)
            listener.onObjectStateChanged();
    }

    public void attachListener(ObjectStateListener listener) {
        if (this.listener == null) {
            this.listener = listener;
            Log.v(TAG, "NO LISTENER PRESENT AS EXPECTED");
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "LISTENER PRESENT!!! BUT THE ACTIVITY WAS STARTED JUST NOW.");
        }
    }

     public void destroy()
    {
        filterCriteria=null;
    }

}
```

The `attachListener(ObjectStateListener listener)` function is called only once in the activity. So, when I open my activity the first time, I get this log from `attachListener` function

```
NO LISTENER PRESENT AS EXPECTED
```

Now, I close the activity and then reopen it. But now I get this log

```
"LISTENER PRESENT!!! BUT THE ACTIVITY WAS STARTED JUST NOW."
```

So, that means the object still lives on even after the activity (and the application) was closed. Is this normal???

So, I tried to destroy the singleton instance using the `destroy()` function in the `onDestroy()` function of Activity.

```
@Override
      protected void onDestroy(){
            filterCriteria.destroy();//Trying to destroy the singleton
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.v(TAG,"Destroying activity");
           }
```

But I got `NullPointerException` on this line `filterCriteria.destroy()`. So, that means android has already made object null, whereas when I see in debug mode, other members of the `Activity` are still alive. Why is only this null?


What is happening!???

Comment: Well... I think you know where the static instances live... Directly under the application scope, which is outside the Activity scope.

Comment: Better discussed in this STO question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle-application-act-crazy

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh then why is only the filterActivity null when other member of the Activity ( static and non-static) live on.

Comment: Is FilterCriteria.getInstance().destroy()  equals to your filterCriteria.destroy()? For 'NullPointerException', better attach logcat of exception

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the method `attachListener()` you are creating a reference to the linked object (even if it is static): **this reference will be binded to the activity lifecycle**.

On the other hand, *filterCriteria* will follow the static field *Java-like* lifecycle (but you can still remove this reference manually).

Comment: Filter criteria is not static

Comment: `private static FilterCriteria filterCriteria` is a static field

Comment: @bonnz : ok. I was talking about the filterCriteria object used in the Activity. FilterCriteria filterCriteria=FilterCriteria.getInstance()

Comment: filterCriteria object in your FilterCriteria class will alive until Garbage Collector runs