# Android - preserve value of variable through the lifecycle of an app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, persistence

I have a mobile app which, once installed, must generate a random `String` that must be kept during its entire lifecycle till uninstalled.

I was thinking of using `static variables`, but as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944564/760893), if I kill my application, the static variable will be null again and will be re-initialized.

What I need to do is create a random string during installation of the APK, and maintain its value while the application is installed, never mind whether it is killed or not.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: use shared preferences for this

Comment: then try to store in sharedpreferences or in sqlite databse

Comment: `public static final int SEVEN = 7;` will always be 7 I guess

Comment: sharedpreference is better

Comment: Why negative vote? I think it was a clear question with a clear doubt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). The official tutorial for how to get and set a `SharedPreference` is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. If you will create a static variable it will be alive till your applications is running when it will be cleared from background your variable value will be null.

For that there are 2 possibilities that can solve your problem:

> 1. Use shared-preferences but you will lose your value if the user go to settings and from there user clear app data
> 2. User Sqlite db you will also lose your data when the user clear app data or user uninstall the application.

use 2 if your data is big other wise 1 is best.Tanks.

Comment: I think, clear data will erase the sqlite db as well. Or you will have keep the db in external memory

Comment: I think it does eras it too... Gonna try.

Comment: @Sonhja I was wrong i checked it by my self when use click on clear data database is also cleared sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

```
When You install your app then you have to store value in shardeprefrence is better option for you
```

Answer (score 1):

Use shared preference

```
private static final String _KEY = "app_unique_key";
private static final String _PREFERENCE = "preference";
public void saveKey(String appKey) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor = preferences.edit();
    preferenceEditor.putString(_KEY, appKey);
    preferenceEditor.apply();
}

public String getAppKey() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString(_KEY, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need use a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) vars... This methods only use for String values if you need to save int,floats, etc... you can create a different methods or just apply code when you need it. I think the best wayt is have in methods because you don't need to repeat code and to control values it's more easy... See the below code to know use sharedPreferences:

```
//Declaration of variables
//This var is name from file of shared preferences, you can save a different files for SharedPreferences
public String StartConfig_File = "sharedPref_StartConfig_File";

//And this one is a SharedPreference var from my StartConfig_File
public String userRemembered = "userRemembered";


//Method to get String from SharedPreference
public String Get_SharedPreferences(Context context, String sharedPref_File,String key_name){

    //Declaration of variables
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPref_File, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String result = sharedPref.getString(key_name, null);

    return result;
}

//Method to set String SharedPreference
public void Set_SharedPreferences(Context context,String sharedPref_File, String key_name,String key_value){

    //Declaration of variables
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPref_File,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putString(key_name,key_value);

    editor.commit();
}
```

And below have a sample to call this methods:

```
//generalMethods is class where I have sharedPreferences methods! Change for your class...

//Initialize values from SharedPreference
generalMethods.Set_SharedPreferences(getActivity(),generalMethods.StartConfig_File,generalMethods.userRemembered ,"MyUser");

//Get value from SharedPreference
String result = generalMethods.Get_SharedPreferences(getActivity(), generalMethods.StartConfig_File, generalMethods.userRemembered );
```

This vars only disappear when app is uninstalled, you can get this values always if you have acces to context... Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would create the String inside the Application. To do this, you need to create a class that extends the `android.app.Application`, put the class name inside the AndroidManifest application tag and then overrides the `onCreate()` with this

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!prefs.containsKey("MY_KEY")) {
        String random = generateYourRandomKey();
        prefs.edit().putString("MY_KEY", random).apply();
    }
}
```

then in every Activity/Service/BrodcastReceiver of your project you can read the value using

```
String random = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(aContext).getString("MY_KEY");
```

where aContext is the context of the Activity/Service and so on.