# Accessing static variable of a finished activity.(Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I have an Activity which has a Static Array list of Array list of Strings which is accessed by the next activity. Now I don't want the next activity to be able to come back to this activity. Will finishing this activity get rid of that array list? If yes then please suggest a solution.

Comment: no. Static data may be deleted by system.

Comment: Try to understand the static objects behavior in Android from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1944564/1739882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create another class with static fields to hold data, these fields can be access through any other class to read/update

Comment: That was what I was thinking about. Thanks for confirming. :)