# why a static instance initialized in Application.onCreate loses its value

Tags: android, static, android-context

I initiate a singleton instance in Application.onCreate, this instance has a member `mApplicationContext` which is initiated by `getApplicationContext()`, and this is the only place mApplicationContext be assigned value. From the crash log, `mApplicationContext` becomes null in certain scenarios, my question is in which this would happen?

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   private Context mApplicationContext = null;
   private ClassicSingleton() {
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public void initiate(Context context){
        this.mApplicationContext = context;
   }
}

public class MyApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        ClassicSingleton.getInstance().initiate(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

I find similar question here [Android static object lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle), but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just guessing since there's no MCVE: Do you have ContentProviders? They are initialised before application onCreate()

Comment: @CommonsWare update my question

Comment: @laalto  I don't see any relation with ContentProviders... answer is no

Comment: Take a look at this question.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android

Comment: By the way, the code you provided probably won't compile because initiate is private.  This does not inspire confidence among those who might try to help you.

Comment: @DaleWilson thanks, but we can't do this, we're developing lib, ClassicSingleton is in our lib, and the initiate part is in host app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a library, don't trust the caller to get it right.  Check!
i.e:

```
public void initiate(Context context){
     if (context == null) {
        throw new Error("Attempt to set null context");
     }
     if (mApplicationContext != null) {
        throw new Error("Why are you setting context twice?");
     }
     this.mApplicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Note the call to `getApplicationContext` ensures that you don't save an Activity context by mistake.  An alternative would be to throw if context != context.getApplicationContext(), but that's probably overkill.

This doesn't fix your bug, but it will help you find it quickly.

Oh-- and you can probably find something better to throw than `Error`

---

Even better:

```
public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
   if(instance == null) {
      throw new Error("you forgot to initiate ClassicSingleton!");
   }
   return instance;
}

public static void initiate(Context context){
     if (context == null) {
        throw new Error("Attempt to set null context");
     }
     if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ClassicSingleton();
     }else{
        // optional
        throw new Error("Why are you initializing ClassicSingleton twice?");
     }
     instance.mApplicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```